# How to validate email using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
        **AngularJS**
<tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>
    <td><input id="email" type="email" ng-model="regform.email" name="uEmail" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
        <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Enter your email.</span>
        <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
        </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

here its give the result true when checking email ab@c and ab@cd.zx123. How to validate email correctly.

Comment: if you have different email validation requirements, then use `type="text"` with an `ng-pattern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
                <td>E-mail:</td>
                <td><input id="email" type="text" ng-model="regform.email" name="uEmail" ng-pattern="EMAIL_REGEXP" required="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
                        <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Enter your email.</span>
                        <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.pattern">This is not a valid email.</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

use this code

$scope.EMAIL_REGEXP = /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(.\w{2,3})+$/;